# Im having issues moving a rectangle on a canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, rect

I created a script to move a rectangle but as it moves, it doesn't remove the previous ones from the canvas.

Here is my javascript.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const box =25;
let snake=[];
snake[0]={x:5*box,y:4*box}

function draw(){
    ctx.rect(snake[0].x, snake[0].y, box, box);

    ctx.fillStroke="black";

    ctx.strokeRect(snake[0].x, snake[0].y, box, box);

    snake.pop();
    snake.unshift({x:6*box,y:4*box});
}

let game=setInterval(draw,100)
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: insert your code html and css pls

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov I edited it out of the post because it was not required for this problem, he was looking for a solution for trailing on a canvas, which is a javascript issue. If you were curious, the CSS was a 10px border, and the html was a canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You can issue `ctx.clearRect` on canvas object on start of each `draw` function call and that will do it for you

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const box = 25;
let snake = [];
snake[0] = {
  x: 5 * box,
  y: 4 * box
}

function draw() {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.rect(snake[0].x, snake[0].y, box, box);

  ctx.fillStroke = "black";


  ctx.strokeRect(snake[0].x, snake[0].y, box, box);

  snake.pop();
  snake.unshift({
    x: 6 * box,
    y: 4 * box
  });


}

let game = setInterval(draw, 350)
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres the correct way to create animations with canvas:

So you **must** create an animation frame the canvas can use to redraw the rectangle every time its moved.

Your issue is that youre drawing the same canvas over itself, so use `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height)` to clear the entire canvas.

Also.... **Please NEVER use intervals with canvas drawing. Only use animation frames like in my function. Just place it at the end of your main draw function, and itll repeat it forever.**

Scroll down and hit "Run code snippet" to see my example run in the browser. As you notice, the rectangle will move smoothly and it leaves no trail behind.

```js
const cvs = document.querySelector(".canvas"),
    ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

let rectX = -30;

function init() {
    ctx.width = 300;
    ctx.height = 300;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height);
    ctx.fillRect(rectX - 25, cvs.height / 2 - 25, 50, 50);
    rectX++;
    if (rectX > 325) {
        rectX = -25;
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(init);
}

init();
```

```html
<canvas class="canvas" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
```